# Como limitar a inserção de tags com React Select

Tags: react, react-select

Estou utilizando o React Select para trabalhar com input tags. Ao inserir algo no input e pressionar enter, a tag é inserida... O ponto é que não consegui achar nada referente a limitações de tags na documentação ou internet. Gostaria de limitar em no máximo umas 10 tags. Tentei usar o YUP para sanar esse problema, mas sem sucesso. Estou usando o Creatable do React Select (https://react-select.com/creatable). Se houvesse algo na documentação pré pronta seria muito melhor. Uma ideia que estava em minha mente, era verificar as tags que tem no estado da aplicação, e então fazer uma condição para saber se há 10 tags ou não. Sugestões sobre essa possível solução são muito úteis.

Trecho de código que estou utilizando:

```
<CreatableSelect
    styles={customStyles}
    inputValue={inputValue}
    components={components}
    isClearable
    isMulti
    menuIsOpen={false}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
    onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
    placeholder="Aperte enter para inserir a tag"
    value={value}
/>
```

Comment: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1392#issuecomment-289631819

Comment: Tentei as possibilidades mas não deu certo cara.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo link que comentei você faria assim com esse seu select

```
const MAX = 100; // CONSTANTE DO COMPONENTE

//...

handleChange = (e) => {
    if (this.state.value.length >= MAX) {
        // TRATAR TAMANHO MAXIMO (ERRO OU ETC)
    }

    // SENAO CONTINUA COM A LOGICA DE ATUALIZAR STATE
};
```